# Statistics resources with examples for a C.S. student

Tags: probability, reference-request, online-resources

I'm a computer science student and is fairly familiar with basic probability (calculating the probability of a event occurring, pmfs and pdfs) but I find it very difficult to grasp the concepts of advanced probability like principles of data reduction (sufficiency, likelihood principle, etc), point and interval estimation, Hypothesis testing, etc. I think it is because I fail to see the intuition behind these concepts.

I tried reading books like [Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126) but most of the books don't give examples (may be with some pictures would help a lot) to explain the concepts well (they do give some examples to apply the theorem but not very helpful to understand the concepts). The online lectures I looked into didn't have Advanced Probability theory. :(

My question is what are some best resources online to understand these well or any books that you would recommend i.e. Books/links that has a pictorial representation of the theorems? By pictorial representation I mean something like [this](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-maxmin-2009-1.pdf) for example; easily understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [this book](http://www.math.uregina.ca/~volodin/MichaelTrosset.pdf). It begins with basic probability, sets, counting, then it moves on to statistical inference. This document is filled with examples and computer code in R, which you might like.

Comment: I think you meant `book by Michael W. Trosset`.

Comment: @Sunil, you are right, someone incorrected edited my post. Since you are using Casella, have you tried looking for online notes based on that book? Also, there is a difference between probability and statistics. This book by Casella is more along the lines of statistics, this might help you in your search.

Comment: Like I said, all the notes I've seen online doesn't give me a good understanding. The book you recommended is very good and I'm going through it now but I think a lot of it has to do with basic probability and lacks a bit on advanced probability like Sufficiency principle. I was more like looking for a same kind of book but for in-depth analysis of advanced probability.

Answer (score 1):

[probability.net](http://probability.net/) is a good online resource for measure-theoretic probability. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: He wants statistics resources not probability.