# books on fundamentals on statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I have mathematical backgroud but I am new to Statistics. So,
could you please advice any books on Statistics and/or Biostatistics for beginners?

Comment: Maybe peruse these: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241930/great-book-on-probability-and-statistics-for-computer-scientists?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115351/statistics-resources-with-examples-for-a-c-s-student?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323668/request-for-statistics-textbook?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402182/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-that-balances-frequentist?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 1):

Statistical Inference by Casella & Berger

This was used as a first introduction to statistics for biostatistics students with a more mathematical background. It covers probability theory, point estimation, hypothesis testing, some asymptotics and regression models.

Comment: Why not to provide some reasons that you think this book is suituable?

Comment: just edited the answer